# Not able to parse simple json object

Tags: python, json, terminal

In my python program, I am using requests library to make post request to the server. It is then returning me information that I convert to the json format as following:

```
    response = requests.post(URL_get_box_info, data = jsonData, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
```

The json formatted response looks like:

```
{'SearchCompletedActions': [
{
'Id': '123', 
'ConnectDateTime': '2021-05-06T15:24:24.2966667Z',
'WorkerId': '123',
'WorkerName': 'aaa',  
'BatchNumber': '155', 
'Documentation': '222',
'OperationalNumber': '234',
'Imei': '123',
'SerialNumber': '123', 
'Completed': True, 
'Pass': True
}
,
{
'Id': '144', 
'ConnectDateTime': '2021-05-06T15:24:24.2966667Z',
'WorkerId': '123',
'WorkerName': '111', 
'BatchNumber': '123', 
'Documentation': '555',
'OperationalNumber': '123',
'Imei': '555',
'SerialNumber': '1233', 
'Completed': True, 
'Pass': True
}]
}
```

All I want to do now is to display this data in a nice format in terminal. I have downloaded jq module but I am not able to parse the json for some reason. I have also tried:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Attempting to use jq to display json in terminal returns an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/programming/json_data $ jq . response2.json
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 26
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue here. The json looks alright to me. I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `response2.json` file that corresponds to the specific error? At least the first couple of lines?

Comment: What you have posted is not JSON. The `.json()` method parses the data to a Python structure already.

Comment: Ah, of course - for one thing, JSON uses double quotes (`"`), never single quotes (`'`)

Comment: JSON is an object serialization format. After `response.json(...)` you have python objects, not JSON. The data you display is not JSON - its a python representation of data. It seems like you are saving _something_ to response2.json _somewhere_. What exactly are you saving? How did you creat this file?

Comment: You could do `open("response2.json", "w").write(response.text)` to save the serialized JSON string.

Comment: Hello. Thanks all for the response. I was not aware that response.json will not actually save it in json format but instead python representation of json. All I simply done after response.json is i printed the data to my python terminal and copy pasted into txt file and saved it as .json. The data that I have shown you is the exact copy of what I have in response2.json file.

Comment: But I am not able to see any differences between the actual examples of json object and my data after I used response.json apart from what you already said regarding the double qoutes ```"``` and single quotes ```'```. Is that the reason that I am not able to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

The output you have from `response.json()` is already JSON decoded, so its actually represented as a dict in python. If you want the valid json format you can do this:

```
import json
json.dumps(data)
```

which will return a string that is in a valid json format or use

```
response.text
```

Comment: That works thanks! Can you clarify something for me though. When I look at the data output after ```data = response.json()``` and data output after ```data2 = json.dumps(data)```. It seems to me that the only difference between the python dict and json is that python dict uses single quotes and json format uses double quotes. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Difference is `data` should be of type dict, and `data2` would be of type string